# Is it a prepositional or a ditransitive phrase?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, descriptive-grammar, ditransitivity

Prepositional phrase?

1. I resolved not to **allow** frivolous preoccupations **to deflect me**. (I cause, not to receive frivolous preoccupations to deflect me)
2. It had, after all, **brought** home **to me** 
   (the whole incident has brought home to me)
3. For Miss Hemmings was **looking up** at **me** with a cold searching gaze.
   (A cold searching gaze was looking up at me (because of Miss Hemmings)
4. but I thought it time I **introduced** myself **to you**
   (I bring myself to you)

Your comments suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the question? Which phrases are under consideratIon? I see four long sentences containing many phrases and clauses. What do you mean by a 'ditransitive phrase'?  Terminology does not mean anything without examples.

Comment: A ditransitive construction is defined as a construction consisting of a two-object structure, which is mainly found with transitive verbs, therefore with a direct object, and in which the SN denoting the recipient is not governed by a preposition but directly by the verb. One of the main features of ditransitive construction is that its two complements are totally independent of each other.

Comment: A prepositional phrase is found with transitive verbs. In this case, the sentence describes the exchange or movement of an object coming from a person and going to a recipient, the object in question can be governed by the prepositions to and for.

Comment: Ditransitive? I managed to pronounce my name with a flourish 
(with a flourish I had managed to pronounce my name)                     Sounds like a ditransitive to me, what do you think?

Comment: From your comment: "...in which the SN denoting the recipient is _not governed by a preposition_ but directly by the verb." [Prepositional phrase:](https://www.google.com/search?q=prepositional+phrase+definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=XuA1WLzFILGw8wes4qtY) "...a modifying phrase consisting of a preposition and its object, usually a noun or pronoun"

Comment: Thank you for the revisions, @Mona. That clears things up nicely. These aren't all the same construction, though; and what you call a 'ditransitive phrase' isn't really a constituent phrase but a part of one.

Comment: Cascabel, a prepositional phrase (ditransitive), in my case, must have his object introduced by to or for: as an example: Lea gave the dog to Lucie. or Lee prepared breakfast for Bruno  My issue is to find the ditransitive verbs [...]

Comment: In general, it is ditransitive if the recipient is movable. ie Lea gave Lucie a dog--Lea gave a dog to Lucie. However, "to Lucie" is now a complement according to some grammars. Others still consider it to be the indirect object formed with a prepositional phrase. See this [link](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/ditransitive.html) for a description of the difference.

Comment: Very interesting Cascabel... this is very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorn of their frivolous elements (but with their original boldfacings), examples 1-4

> 1. *I did not **allow** them **to deflect me**.*
> 2. *It **brought** home **to me** the whole incident.*
> 3. *Miss Hemmings was **looking up** at **me**.*
> 4. *I **introduced** myself **to you**.*

represent several different kinds of construction, and the various prepositions are variously governed by the construction or the predicate.

The *to* appearing in ditransitive sentences marking the receiver of the trajector 
(usually the trajector is the direct object) is governed by and participates in the [Dative Alternation](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/169710/15299):

- *She sent/gave/donated/paid **me** $45.00 ~  She sent/gave/donated/paid $45.00 to **me**.*

Some people have wanted to call one of these `me`'s -- but not the other -- **The Indirect Object**.
However, there is no agreement as to which one is the true, the blushful Indirect Object, since some say the one **without** the preposition is it, while others claim it's the one **with** the preposition.

And then there is *for*, which is a benefactive construction representing someone who benefits, and can be attached optionally to any volitional activity sentence.

- *I held the door open (for him).*
- *I fixed his car (for him)*.
- *I dug a clam (for him).*

[This can masquerade as an indirect object](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90534/15299), **provided** that the object of benefactive for actually does receive the trajector, in which case it can undergo Dative Alternation just like *to*:

- *I dug him a clam.*

but if not, then *for* phrases doesn't undergo Dative:

- **I fixed him his car.*

But none of the examples above are ditransitive predicates.

- (1) *Allow `NP` to `VP`* is a normal infinitive complement clause with the infinitive complementizer *to* (which is a preposition in the same sense that *the* is an adjective). *Allow* here could either be a [B-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) predicate -- where the subject of the infinitive becomes an object in the upstairs clause, even if it doesn't belong there, as in *She did not allow the shit to hit the fan*; or a B-Equi construction -- where the subject of the infinitive plays an actual role as patient or recipient of the main verb, as in *I did not allow him to move an inch.*
- (2) *Bring home to* is an idiomatic predicate that means 'deeply and permanently impress'.
  *Bring home to* is a unit and can't be split; *to* and *home* is part of the idiom. *Home* is not a direct object of *bring,* for instance; it can't be passivized -- *This brought it all home to me*  is fine, but not **Home was brought it all to me by this*.  The actual object of *bring home to* is the experiencer, but a *to*-experiencer phrase is not obligatory with this idiom. One can simply say *This just brings home how important it is,* with the usual indefinite experiencer unmentioned.
- (3) *Looking up at `NP`* is the same preposition construction as *looking at* -- i.e, an arbitrarily-governed transitivizing preposition *at* governed by *look*, with the added wrinkle that of a directional component. This is not the phrasal verb *look up*, of *look up the word/look it up*, but the straightforward directional 'look up the stairway/look up it'.
- (4) *Introduce `NP₁` to `NP₂`* is a [reciprocal construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/152096/15299) that governs the preposition *to*, even though one always introduces individuals simultaneously (there are different conditions in introducing an individual to a group, and other contexts) so that, if I introduce `NP₁` to `NP₂`, then I have also effectively introduced `NP₂` to `NP₁`. Thus the directionality sense of *to* is not involved with _introduce `X` to `Y`, just like the *grid location* sense of *at* is not invoked by the construction *look at `X`.*

Executive summary: Prepositions have complex instantiations, and may or may not mean anything.

Comment: Thanks, John, I really appreciate it. I have to sleep now, but I will look into this more closely, tomorrow morning.

Comment: Hi @John, so if I am not wrong, this sentence is a ditransitive: she gave  [a quick glance] [back to her book]
                                                                                                              - a quick glance was giving back to her book (by her) because she causes the book to have a second look. X cause Y to receive Z.  What did she give? a quick glance. Is this correct?

Comment: and this one too: It was this utterance (x), made so matter-of-factly, which quite threw me (Y) off my balance (Z)

X cause Y to move Z
This utterance caused me to move off my balance 
With a positional verb and an animated goal: ‘throw’

Comment: The last one is a cleft sentence, but I 'd like to think that ''threw me off balance'', is ditransitive.

Comment: @Mona: (1) You can't passivize small verb constructions like _give a glance_; *_a quick glance was given back to her book_ is ungrammatical. (2) Again, a small verb construction; you can say _My balance was thrown off_, by itself, but then you're speaking of your physical vertical equilibrium, not metaphorically of some proposition. And _throw me off balance_ is not ditransitive; it is causative, but adjective phrases like _off balance_ aren't direct objects. Learn to distinguish metaphor themes from syntactic constructions; they vary each other.